# iOS Bluetooth Connectivty via Navigation Through Next Page

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I have a question concerning passing the currentSession over to the next page.
I have tested and has established a bluetooth session successfully on the first page view controller. Now my question is, how do i pass the current session over to the next page because after navigating to the next page, the bluetooth connection is lost. So after navigating to the next page, the current session is lost. This was tested by sending a random image with two phones. However, if prompt bluetooth connection on the nextpageController the second time, the picture could be send.

View controller.M:

```
-(IBAction)btnBluetoothConnect:(id)sender {
    picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;

    [picker show];
}


- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)pk didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *)session {
    self.currentSession = session;
    session.delegate = self;
    [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
}

- (void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)pk {
    picker.delegate = nil;
}


- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {
    switch (state) {
        case GKPeerStateConnected:
            NSLog(@"connected");
            if (GKPeerStateConnected) {
                self.progress = [[ProgressAlertView alloc] init];
                progress.delegate = self;
                progress.task = @selector(compute);
                [progress start];
            }
            break;

        case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
            NSLog(@"disconnected");
            currentSession = nil;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)compute{
    [self updateUIWithProgress:0.0 andMessage:@"3"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    if([progress isCancelled]){
        self.progress = nil;
        return;
    }
    [self updateUIWithProgress:0.4 andMessage:@"2"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    if([progress isCancelled]){
        self.progress = nil;
        return;
    }
    [self updateUIWithProgress:0.6 andMessage:@"1"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    if([progress isCancelled]){
        self.progress = nil;
        return;
    }
    [self updateUIWithProgress:0.8 andMessage:@"0"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    if([progress isCancelled]){
        self.progress = nil;
        return;
    }
    else
        [self updateUIWithProgress:1.0 andMessage:@"Start!"];
    NSLog(@"Woohahaha");
    **[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next page" sender:self];**

    //process the data here or send a notification for data processing
    //when this method returns, the progress alert view disappears.
}
```

NextPageController.m:

```
-(IBAction)btnSend:(id)sender{


    if(currentSession){
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"4.png"]], .7);
        [self.currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:imageData withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
    }
}


- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}

- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)pk didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *)session {
    self.currentSession = session;
    session.delegate = self;
    [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
}

- (void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)pk {
    picker.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I did it the right way or not, but I have an app that has many pages and I needed to maintain that connection throughout them all.  So I put all my Bluetooth connection code in a singleton class that each view controller could talk to.  That way it can handle all of the communication each page can just tell it what it wants sent.

So this is a great tutorial for singleton classes 
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

as far as the Bluetooth stuff it looks like you have all the right methods.  Just put them in your singleton class.  Then when you reference the class *(MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];)* then just create a sendCommand method of sorts to send whatever communication you want like this [sharedManager sendCommand:data];

So you have your bluetooth class.  You add a bluetoothconnect method with something like this code in it

```
picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
[picker show];
```

then from your view controller class you reference your singleton class with something like what the tutorial showed.

```
MyManager sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
```

then you can call your new method: [sharedManager bluetoothconnect];

Comment: Can you briefly show me the code? I took 3 days to solve but still cannot. If possible, email me? devilishkai@gmail.com THANK YOU! I need this help for my project.

Comment: I've read the tutorial and I still cannot solve it. I add a file NSObject called bluetooth as the singleton class.Now what i want to ask is how do i call a particular method example-(void)bluetoothconnect from the bluetooth singleton class? I want to access this method from another class called viewController. That method is separated from the +(id)sharedManager class. Am i doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Hi,sorry to bother you again. I have put the codes below in a method in my bluetooth class. The method is called -(void)send. So in the next page ViewController class, i call this method [sharedManager send]; Now the problem is, i do not know how to store the data into an image from the method receiveData I do not know how to call the image as the image view declared in my bluetooth class is different from the image view referenced from the NextPageViewcontroller class. The codes i put in the send method is same as the one in the IBaction btnSend method.

Comment: I'm sorry could you include some code?  I'm kind of confused by your question here...